# Horizontal pod autoscaling configuration reset

Tags: kubernetes-helm, spinnaker, horizontal-scaling

As per our environment, we are using spinnaker for continuous deployment, as soon as we are triggering the pipeline from the spinnaker.

Again hpa (Autoscaling) configuration in the terms of currentReplica and desiredReplica set to zero.

Could you please have a look into this and help us to get it sorted.

[image: hpa config on Spinnaker]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved in `Spinnaker Version 1.14.9`.